# C++ VS2010 difference between "Multihreaded DLL" and "Multithreaded"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, ide

I created a DLL in VS2010 and used "Multithreaded" under *C/C++->Code generation->Runtime library*.

Now I wondered what the difference between "Multithreaded" and "Multithreaded-DLL" is.

Comment: Fix the spelling errors in the title. Until then, here's a down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *multithreaded* option will link the CRT statically, whereas *multithreaded DLL* will link to a dynamic library.

With the former option, you'll get a larger binary, but you won't have to install Visual Studio redistributables everywhere you use it.

Comment: With "distributables" you mean vcredist_x86.exe?